# Get all completions for a command prefix

Tags: bash, shell, autocomplete

Given a prefix like `git che` I'm trying to get the following list:`checkout, cherry, cherry-pick`

[`compgen`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/151118/understand-compgen-builtin-command) only works for commands but not the initial command but not for additional parts.

Comment: https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash

Comment: A general solution for arbitrary commands.

Comment: here's how with bash_completion http://askubuntu.com/a/345150